# Resolving dependencies with windsor castle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I have a factory class with dependencies on a repository class. How do I resolve the dependencies within my factory class? I could pass the dependency from my controller into the factory, but that doesn't seem like the right way.

```
public BarFactory(IFoo foo) {

}
```

For controllers you can just stick the dependencies in the constructor and the controller factory deals with it, but for everything else I'm not so sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you need a factory when using windsor the recommended approach would be to use the TypeFactoryFacility. You can find all about it in this link: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx

In general it is much easier then writing your own factories. Just create the interface and Windsor does the heavy lifting.